# How to stop bot from silently going offline for no reason and no console errors

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Ok, so basically I made a bot that worked fine but I made a huge mistake by making everything in index.js. So I have decided to start another bot and make everything separate from index.js. Before I haven't had discord.js-command installed but on this bot I used it. Since then my bot executes every command correctly and does the job but after some time it goes offline without reporting anything except `(node:9072) DeprecationWarning: Collection#filterArray: use Collection#filter instead` in the console.

I have tried adding autoReconnect but it didn't wokr out. Still the same problem.

Also before I did not have changing Bot Status and I added it with this code:

```
bot.on("ready" , () => {
        bot.user.setStatus("dnd")
        console.log('Ready!');
        
        setInterval(() => {
            bot.user.setStatus('dnd')
              bot.user.setActivity(`with MEMBERS`, {type: 'PLAYING'}); 
          }, 1);
      });
      
      bot.on('ready', () => {
        bot.user.setStatus('dnd')
          setInterval(() => {
              bot.user.setActivity(`lawliet#0599`, {type: 'WATCHING'}); 
          }, 2);
      });
```

I tought this was the problem but I am not sure about that fact.

I did not connect bot to any of hosting platforms. It is only on my computer and I expected it to work from the moment I do `node .` in console to the moment I use Ctrl+c in terminal or when I close it entirely.
Instead it just goes online, I can use few commands before it goes offline.
After that I have to reconnect it manually.

If anyone knows how to fix this problem please take your time. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably getting disconnected by the discord server because you are sending too many requests.

I haven't dug too much into the API, but both of your `setInterval` statements are calling `bot.user.setActivity` each few milliseconds (1 and 2). I don't know what are you trying to achieve with that but it is probably not the desired behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, it was set to 1800 and 1600 but I tought changing it to 2 and 1 would change something. I will make some research how to fix that since im not using a lot of requests just few, such as `$avatar` and `$mute`. And then bot goes completely offline.

I will make an update If I find anything useful.

Anyways thank you for you help.

Comment: No, what I mean is `bot.user.setStatus()` and `bot.user.setActivity()` both send requests to discord server. You should probably just call them once, as calling them each 1 and 2 milliseconds will get you disconnected.